# SimpleRestProvider Empty Resource

Tags: react-admin

I am trying to Use Cockpit CMS as a Rest Backend, however i fail to understand the Logic of the Rest Provider and the Resource. Apparently we call GET_LIST first - which works fine, resource params etc is set. but it also calls GET_MANY with an emtpy Resource. As you can see i replaced

```
url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
```

with

```
url = `${apiUrl}/collections/get/testing?token=SOMETOKEN&filter[_id]=5e2037a536383609f00001cc`;
```

which produces no error, but i fail to understand why resource is emtpy/undefined at the get_many call.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import authProvider from './cockpitAuthProvider';
import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';
import simpleRestProvider from './simpleRestProviderlistCollections';
const App = () => (
    <Admin authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={simpleRestProvider('http://someurl/cockpit-0.9.3/api')}>
        <Resource name="testing" list={ListGuesser} />
    </Admin>
);
export default App;
```

simpleRestProviderlistCollections.js:

```
import { stringify } from 'query-string';
import {
    fetchUtils,
    GET_LIST,
    GET_ONE,
    GET_MANY,
    GET_MANY_REFERENCE,
    CREATE,
    UPDATE,
    UPDATE_MANY,
    DELETE,
    DELETE_MANY,
} from 'react-admin';
**
 * Maps react-admin queries to a simple REST API
 *
 * The REST dialect is similar to the one of FakeRest
 * @see https://github.com/marmelab/FakeRest
 * @example
 * GET_LIST     => GET http://my.api.url/posts?sort=['title','ASC']&range=[0, 24]
 * GET_ONE      => GET http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * GET_MANY     => GET http://my.api.url/posts?filter={ids:[123,456,789]}
 * UPDATE       => PUT http://my.api.url/posts/123
 * CREATE       => POST http://my.api.url/posts
 * DELETE       => DELETE http://my.api.url/posts/123
 */
export default (apiUrl, httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson) => {
    /**
     * @param {String} type One of the constants appearing at the top if this file, e.g. 'UPDATE'
     * @param {String} resource Name of the resource to fetch, e.g. 'posts'
     * @param {Object} params The data request params, depending on the type
     * @returns {Object} { url, options } The HTTP request parameters
     */
    const convertDataRequestToHTTP = (type, resource, params) => {
        let url = '';
        console.log(`convertDataRequestToHTTP ${resource}`);
        const options = {};
        switch (type) {
            case GET_LIST: {
                console.log(`convertDataRequestToHTTP GET_LIST ${resource}`);
                const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
                const { field, order } = params.sort;
                const query = {
                    sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
                    range: JSON.stringify([
                        (page - 1) * perPage,
                        page * perPage - 1,
                    ]),
                    filter: JSON.stringify(params.filter),
                };
                //added a / before ?
                //url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/get/?${stringify(query)}`;
                url = `${apiUrl}/collections/get/${resource}?token=SOMETOKEN`;
                break;
            }
            case GET_ONE:
                url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
               break;
            case GET_MANY: {
                console.log(`convertDataRequestToHTTP GET_MANY ${resource}`);
                const query = {                 
                    filter: JSON.stringify({ id: params.ids }),
                };
                //url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
                url = `${apiUrl}/collections/get/testing?token=SOMETOKEN&filter[_id]=5e2037a536383609f00001cc`;
                break;
            }
            case GET_MANY_REFERENCE: {
                console.log("convertDataRequestToHTTP GET_MANY_REFERENCE");
                const { page, perPage } = params.pagination;
                const { field, order } = params.sort;
                const query = {
                    sort: JSON.stringify([field, order]),
                    range: JSON.stringify([
                        (page - 1) * perPage,
                        page * perPage - 1,
                    ]),
                    filter: JSON.stringify({
                        ...params.filter,
                        [params.target]: params.id,
                    }),
                };
                url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}?${stringify(query)}`;
                break;
            }
            case UPDATE:
                url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
                options.method = 'PUT';
                options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
                break;
            case CREATE:
                url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}`;
                options.method = 'POST';
                options.body = JSON.stringify(params.data);
                break;
            case DELETE:
                url = `${apiUrl}/${resource}/${params.id}`;
                options.method = 'DELETE';
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error(`Unsupported fetch action type ${type}`);
        }
        return { url, options };
    };

    /**
     * @param {Object} response HTTP response from fetch()
     * @param {String} type One of the constants appearing at the top if this file, e.g. 'UPDATE'
     * @param {String} resource Name of the resource to fetch, e.g. 'posts'
     * @param {Object} params The data request params, depending on the type
     * @returns {Object} Data response
     */
    const convertHTTPResponse = (response, type, resource, params) => {
        const { headers, json } = response;
        switch (type) {
            case GET_LIST:
                var jnew = json.entries
                return { 
                    data: jnew.map(resource => ({ ...resource, id: resource._id }) ),
                    total: 1,
                };  
            case GET_MANY_REFERENCE:
                var jnew = json.entries
                console.log(json)
                return { 
                    data: jnew.map(resource => ({ ...resource, id: resource._id }) ),
                    total: 1,
                };              
            case CREATE:
                return { data: { ...params.data, id: json._id } };
            default:
                return { data: json };
        }
    };

    /**
     * @param {string} type Request type, e.g GET_LIST
     * @param {string} resource Resource name, e.g. "posts"
     * @param {Object} payload Request parameters. Depends on the request type
     * @returns {Promise} the Promise for a data response
     */
    return (type, resource, params) => {
        // simple-rest doesn't handle filters on UPDATE route, so we fallback to calling UPDATE n times instead
        if (type === UPDATE_MANY) {
            return Promise.all(
                params.ids.map(id =>
                    httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${id}`, {
                        method: 'PUT',
                        body: JSON.stringify(params.data),
                    })
                )
            ).then(responses => ({
                data: responses.map(response => response.json),
            }));
        }
        // simple-rest doesn't handle filters on DELETE route, so we fallback to calling DELETE n times instead
        if (type === DELETE_MANY) {
            return Promise.all(
                params.ids.map(id =>
                    httpClient(`${apiUrl}/${resource}/${id}`, {
                        method: 'DELETE',
                    })
                )
            ).then(responses => ({
                data: responses.map(response => response.json),
            }));
        }

        const { url, options } = convertDataRequestToHTTP(
            type,
            resource,
            params
        );
        console.log(resource)
        console.log(options)
        console.log(url)
        return httpClient(url, options).then(response =>
            convertHTTPResponse(response, type, resource, params)
        );
    };
};
```

this also seems to be the problem at the question/solution of: [How is the correct way to have multiple dataProviders in react-admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889909/how-is-the-correct-way-to-have-multiple-dataproviders-in-react-admin#comment105676850_52893150)

Because if i do it the way of the solution i also get the error:

```
TypeError: dataProviderMapping.dataProvider is not a function
```

due to the emtpy resource.

i also tried this: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-data-json-server/src/index.ts implementation which should work like this:

getList GET http://my.api.url/posts?_sort=title&_order=ASC&_start=0&_end=24&title=bar

getMany GET http://my.api.url/posts/123, GET http://my.api.url/posts/456, GET http://my.api.url/posts/789

however, in my case it produces http://my.api.url/s/123 (s because resource is empty)

Api Returns:
http://192.168.0.163/cockpit-0.9.3/api/collections/get/testing?token=TOKEN

```
{"fields":{"bla":{"name":"bla","type":"text","localize":false,"options":[]},"blup":{"name":"blup","type":"text","localize":false,"options":[]}},"entries":[{"bla":"dgfhs","blup":"sdgfh","_mby":"5ddc222d36383611fa00025a","_by":"5ddc222d36383611fa00025a","_modified":1579169696,"_created":1579169696,"_id":"5e2037a036383609f0000270"},{"bla":"sgdf","blup":"sdfg","_mby":"5ddc222d36383611fa00025a","_by":"5ddc222d36383611fa00025a","_modified":1579169701,"_created":1579169701,"_id":"5e2037a536383609f00001cc"}],"total":2}
```

http://192.168.0.163/cockpit-0.9.3/api/collections/get/testing?token=TOKEN&filter[_id]=5e2037a536383609f00001cc

```
{
  "fields": {
    "bla": {
      "name": "bla",
      "type": "text",
      "localize": false,
      "options": []
    },
    "blup": {
      "name": "blup",
      "type": "text",
      "localize": false,
      "options": []
    }
  },
  "entries": [
    {
      "bla": "sgdf",
      "blup": "sdfg",
      "_mby": "5ddc222d36383611fa00025a",
      "_by": "5ddc222d36383611fa00025a",
      "_modified": 1579169701,
      "_created": 1579169701,
      "_id": "5e2037a536383609f00001cc"
    }
  ],
  "total": 1
}
```