# How to use multiple entrypoints in api platform admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, api-platform.com

I am using [api-platform.com](https://api-platform.com/) and I have microservices in backend. e.g. http://example.com:8511/api http://example.com:8512/api http://example.com:8513/api

Each entrypoint contains different resources. e.g `books`, `categories`, `media` and they have relations with each other. How can i use all resources from all entrypoints in one react-admin app? I think i need to create custom `hydraDataProvider` function.
Here explains how to do it in simple `react-admin` app [Is it possible to have multiple dataProviders in react-admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724915/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-dataproviders-in-react-admin). But i need to do it in `api-platform`

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution to this?
I am looking to do something similar.
https://github.com/api-platform/admin/issues/368

Comment: I'm still looiking for solution